# How to merge the duplicates rows in pandas dataframe with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I'm trying to merge the duplicates in the resulting .csv but unable to get the desired result.

My below code works just fine.

```
def inputCsv():
    r = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers, params=params)
    with open("input.csv", "w") as f:
        f.writelines(r.text.splitlines(True))
    df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
    return df

def outputCsv():

    with open("secret.json", "w") as file:
        auth = ssm.get_parameter(Name="/something/something/creds", WithDecryption=True)
        file.write(str(auth['Parameter']['Value']))
        os.environ["creds"] = "secret.json"


    rows = []
    with open(rb'output.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_file:
        timestamp = datetime.now()        
        df = getCsv()
        if 'Name' in df.columns:
            df.rename(columns = {"Name": "team", "Total": "cost"}, inplace = True)
        df.insert(0, 'date',timestamp)
        df.insert(1, 'resource_type', "pod")
        df.insert(2, 'resource_name', "kubernetes")
        df.insert(3, 'cluster_name', "eks-cluster")
        df.drop(["CPU", "GPU", "RAM", "PV", "Network", "LoadBalancer", "External", "Shared", "Efficiency"], axis=1, inplace=True)
        df['team'] = df['team'].map(squads).fillna(df['team'])

        df.to_csv(out_file, index=False)
```

But the resulting output looks like below because of duplicates inserted via `df.map` function.

```
date,resource_type,resource_name,cluster_name,team,cost
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,billing,0.201
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,sre-infra-and-release,0.238
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,sre-infra-and-release,0.008
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,sre-infra-and-release,0.836
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,growth,0.513
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,sre-observability,3.633
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,order-platform,1.963
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,menu,0.46
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,ncr,3.291
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,order-platform,4.846
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,grocery-affordability,0.171
```

I want that the duplicated `sre-infra-and-release` to be merged with single row with cost being sum together.

tried to use this below but some how is not working, the resultant file still had the duplicated rows.

```
df.groupby(['team']).sum()
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result. Without an example, it's hard for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You need to group all columns except cost, and then sum on cost.
something like -

```
df.groupby(['date','resource_type','resource_name','cluster_name','team'])['cost'].sum()
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Does not works, the resulting file still has duplicates.

Comment: I'll need to re read the .csv for this? @Rajkumar

Comment: Yes, as you have final csv and it contains duplicates. You can just read one more time your final csv. And group all columns except cost and write it to another csv.

Comment: Is it possible that instead of re reading the output csv again, If i can put the results in memory, use group by and then only generate the output csv?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt')
df.groupby(["date","resource_type","resource_name","cluster_name","team"]).agg({"cost": sum}).reset_index()
```

with file.txt:

```
date,resource_type,resource_name,cluster_name,team,cost
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,billing,0.201
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,sre-infra-and-release,0.238
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,sre-infra-and-release,0.008
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,sre-infra-and-release,0.836
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,growth,0.513
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,sre-observability,3.633
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,order-platform,1.963
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,menu,0.46
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,ncr,3.291
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,order-platform,4.846
2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080,pod,kubernetes,eks-cluster,grocery-affordability,0.171
```

Works for me. The result is:

```
date    resource_type   resource_name   cluster_name    team    cost
0   2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080  pod kubernetes  eks-cluster billing 0.201
1   2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080  pod kubernetes  eks-cluster grocery-affordability   0.171
2   2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080  pod kubernetes  eks-cluster growth  0.513
3   2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080  pod kubernetes  eks-cluster menu    0.460
4   2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080  pod kubernetes  eks-cluster ncr 3.291
5   2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080  pod kubernetes  eks-cluster order-platform  6.809
6   2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080  pod kubernetes  eks-cluster sre-infra-and-release   1.082
7   2022-12-30 14:56:08.383080  pod kubernetes  eks-cluster sre-observability   3.633
```

Comment: Is it possible that instead of re reading the output csv again, If i can put the results in memory, use group by and then only generate the output csv?

Answer (score 0):

Able to solve the issue like below.

```
df.groupby(["date","resource_type","resource_name","cluster_name","team"]).agg({"cost": sum}).reset_index().to_csv(out_file, index=False)
```